# Count Files In Subfolder

Tags: python, subdirectory

I want to be able to count the amount of images I have in each folder. I want to be able to run the Python program in the main folder where I have the subfolders and get a count of the files in each subfolder.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os

h=len([name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)])
print ([os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if     os.path.isdir(name)])
print (h)


path = '/Users/olivermee/Pictures/Instagram/1.Muscle Car Monday/Unused/'
mn = 20
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))    # get all directories
```

Comment: Checkout [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: Python 3.4, and does os.walk work on mac? Because it says only on windows or unix on the website

Comment: os.walk works great on Unix or OS X

Comment: @OliverMee OSX is UNIX. Officially, it is a variant of UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
for dir,subdir,files in os.walk('\\path\\path'):
    print dir,' ', str(len(files))
```

Prints the subdir, and file count (Python 2.7)

Comment: Any idea why it prints nothing?

Comment: Your code, or mine? If you mean yours, I have no idea. If you mean mine, it works here, so I still have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
def fcount(path, exts=[".jpg"]):
    count=0    
    exts=[e.lower() for e in exts]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for d in dirs:
            p=os.path.join(root, d)
            ff=[fn for fn in os.listdir(p) if any(fn.lower().endswith(e) for e in exts) ]
            if ff:
                count+=len(ff)

    return count
```

Comment: This is just a small framework that shows how it works. Modify to suit. This will create a dictionary of all files that start with `"B"`. It is trivial to modify for directories, different conditions.

Comment: Sorry, the B thing wasnt supposed to be there. I was trying to test it earlier and accidentally left it in. Also when it prints any idea how to remove all of the  "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10574f3a8>"

Comment: I feel like im being really annoying right now but, how can i modify it to count the amount of images rather than the amount of folders. Thanks

Comment: That is counting files. What is an image? `.jpg`? `.png`? Upper and lower case? You need to be more specific.

Comment: They are all .jpg images, the names of them all are also IMG_(four random numbers).jpg. Like this "IMG_0165.JPG"